# Tensorflow reshape tensor gives None dimension

Tags: tensorflow

I have used the model described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/recurrent/index.html) on the 0.6.0 branch. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0.6.0/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py). I have done some minor changes to the linked code.

In my code I create two models, one for training and one for validation, very similar as it is done in the Tensorflow Tutorial.

```
with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=None, initializer=initializer):
    m = PTBModel_User(is_training=True, config=config, name='Training model')
with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=True, initializer=initializer):
    mtest = PTBModel_User(is_training=False, config=config_valid, name='Validation model')
```

The first model, the one for training, seems to be created just fine, but the second, used for validation, does not. The output gets a None dimension! The row I'm refering to is on row 134 in the [linked](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0.6.0/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py) code:

`output = tf.reshape(tf.concat(1, outputs), [-1, size])`

I've added these lines right after the reshape of the output:

```
output_shape = output.get_shape()
print("Model num_steps:", num_steps)
print("Model batch_size:", batch_size)
print("Output dims", output_shape[0], output_shape[1])
```

and that gives me this:

```
Model num_steps: 400
Model batch_size: 1
Output dims Dimension(None) Dimension(650)
```

This problem only happens with the 'validation model', not with the 'training model'. For the 'training model' I get expected output:

```
Model num_steps: 400
Model batch_size: 2
Output dims Dimension(800) Dimension(650)
```

(Note that with the 'validation model' I use a `batch_size=1` instead of `batch_size=2` that I use for the training model)

From what I understand, using `-1` as input to the `reshape` function, will figure the output shape out automagically! But then why do I get None? Nothing in my config fed to the model has a None value.

Thank you for all the help and tips!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** A dimension being `None` simply means that shape inference could not determine an exact shape for the `output` tensor, *at graph-building time*. When you run the graph, the tensor will have the appropriate *run-time* shape.

If you're not interested in how shape inference works, you can stop reading now.

Shape inference applies local rules, based on a "shape function" that takes the shapes of the inputs to an operation and computes (possibly incomplete) shapes for the outputs of an operation. To figure out why [`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape) gives an incomplete shape, we have to look at its inputs, and work backwards:

- The `shape` argument to `tf.reshape()` includes a `[-1]`, which means "figure the output shape automagically" based on the shape of the `tensor` input.
- The `tensor` input is the output of [`tf.concat()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#concat) on the [same line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4be56f381cd000e91f79209aaf150636db6fb840/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L134).
- The inputs to `tf.concat()` are computed by a [`tf.mul()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#mul) in [`BasicLSTMCell.__call__()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/fd464caaa40cfa16c81712939e39bd14d88c6fd4/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L209). The `tf.mul()` op multiplies the result of a [`tf.tanh()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#tanh) and a [`tf.sigmoid()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#sigmoid) op.
- The `tf.tanh()` op produces an output of size `[?, hidden_size]`, and the `tf.sigmoid()` op produces an output of size `[batch_size, hidden_size]`.

The `tf.mul()` op performs [NumPy-style broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html). A dimension will only be broadcast if it has size 1. Consider three cases where we compute `tf.mul(x, y)`:

1. If `x` has shape `[1, 10]`, and `y` has shape `[5, 10]`, then broadcasting will happen, and the output shape will be `[5, 10]`.
2. If `x` has shape `[1, 10]`, and `y` has shape `[1, 10]`, then there will be no broadcasting, and the output shape will be `[1, 10]`.
3. However, if `x` has shape `[1, 10]`, and `y` has shape `[?, 10]`, there is insufficient static information to tell whether broadcasting will happen (even though we happen to know that case 2 applies at runtime).

Therefore, when `batch_size` is 1, the `tf.mul()` op produces an output with the shape `[?, hidden_size]`; but when `batch_size` is greater than 1, the output shape is `[batch_size, hidden_size]`.

Where shape inference breaks down, it can be appropriate to use the [`Tensor.set_shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor.set_shape) method to add information. This would potentially be useful in the `BasicLSTMCell` implementation, where we know more than it is possible to infer about the shapes of the outputs.

Comment: If x has shape [1,10] and y has shape [1,10], then whether or not broadcasting occurs the result will have shape [1,10], right? So why does that distinction need to be made?